# Android - return a sorted, duplicate-free contacts list

Tags: android, listview, sorting, android-contacts

I'd like to ask how can I return a sorted, duplicate-free contacts list on Android? I've found some similar questions asked and I almost got my code working (it does return a contacts list), but it comes back with a lot of duplicates and not sorted. I've been trying all kinds of ways, but it still doesn't work. My goal is to be able to click on a contact and be taken to next page where that contact info will be used.

Code so far:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.contacts_view);

    cursor1 = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
    startManagingCursor(cursor1);

    String [] from = { ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, 
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID};
    int[] to = {android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2};

    SimpleCursorAdapter listadapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, cursor1, from, to);

    setListAdapter(listadapter);

    lv = getListView();
    lv.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);

}
```